# Database note taker Oracle db

Tags: oracle, documentation

I'm trying to find a tool that will help me to build a documentation for a database.
I need to write comment on column / table and to have a summary of data flow that creates/modifies data and most important, at a conceptual level what data means. I'm also looking for a free tool

After a long search, I found out http://databasenotetaker.com/ which seems to be suitable for my purposes.
My database is Oracle.
From the documentation they say it potentially support every database but I can't connect to Oracle.
I don't know how to specify the driver in the connection window:

[image]

Comment: Hello, it looks like the tool connects by ODBC. Do you have in the list of drivers some for Oracle ? It seems to me that if you don't have a driver in the select list , it means that this is not yet compatible. Where did you read it was ?

Comment: http://databasenotetaker.com/database-documentation/database-documentation-frequent-questions.aspx   "Can Database Note Taker connect to other database platforms?"

Answer (score 4):

According to their documentation

**

### Can Database Note Taker connect to other database platforms?

**

Yes and we will add support for other platforms in the future. So long as it's a relational database and there are freely available connectors, then Database Note Taker will be able to work with it. Out of the box you can connect to Microsoft Sql Server, and MySql via ODBC."

Out of the box you can't connect to Oracle, therefore you need a driver. Check with them to understand which driver they mean when they said "freely available connectors". Out-of-the-box in this context refers to the drivers that appear in the selection list.

My advice: Ask them which kind of driver do you need. If standard ODBC is ok, you must download the ODBC driver from Oracle.

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

**Important** Check whether this product supports 64 bits or it is 32, in order to select the right ODBC driver.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No, Database Note Taker does not support Oracle. There is no way you can add this functionality yourself. While the architecture supports it, no Oracle driver exists.

The developers have indicated an interest in adding Oracle support, but do not use Oracle themselves.